# how to install chromedriver specific to local chrome browser version in selenium using python?

Tags: python, selenium, user-interface, browser, selenium-chromedriver

I wanted to install chromedriver that supports the current local chrome browser version in runtime.

Code should work like this:

```
1. First checks version of chrome browser.
2. Install the chromedriver corresponds to that chrome browser version.
```

I have tried:
`pip install chromedriver-py`

but it installs latest version of chromedriver, but I want the version that suppports local chrome browser.

please help me if anyone finds a solution.

Comment: Here three versions of charome: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want us to write the whole code.. Anyhow, here is just a vague idea which you can implement with a bit of research:

---

Regarding your first step:

> 1. First checks version of chrome browser.

According to the [Google ChromeDriver requirements](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#requirements) the download path of Chrome can be expected in a certain download path, depending on your system. You either could check (like another user has done it: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41354/programmatically-determine-chrome-browser-version-regardless-of-os) the chrome version via `chrome.exe --version` or read the file names of the directory chrome.exe is installed:

[image]

The first file (maybe verify via regex) is my chrome version, `87.0.4280.88`. I'd suggest taking a look at [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory).

> 2. Install the chromedriver corresponds to that chrome browser version.

That's also doable with a little bit of research. You got all the download links on https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads. Just check for matching version and grab the respective link. If that doesn't suit your needs, maybe consider pre-installing the versions and implementing the proper one (depending on the version of the chrome browser).